# How to stop Vlingo Voice Talk coming up on double-tapping?

Tags: uninstallation, voice-command, keyboard-shortcuts

Maybe my home button is getting a bit bouncy but I'm getting this annoying app constantly coming up, blasting out "What would you like do". O/S 2.3.5.

Is there a way of reconfiguring double-tap or disabling this app without going a custom ROM?